# Spring transaction propagation - Service vs DAO

Tags: java, spring, dao, jdbctemplate, transactional

I have a Service class like below:

```
@Service("MyService")
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    MyDao dao;

    public void process() {
        getFromDao();
        // getMoreFromDao();
        // process();
        // if all good, then
        doStuff();
    }

    public void getFromDao() {
        // do some stuff
        dao.getData();
    }

    @Transactional(transactionManager="simpleDatasourceTxMgr", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void doStuff() {
        dao.saveData(1);
        dao.saveData(2);
        dao.saveData(3);
   }
}
```

The DAO called is:

```
@Repository
public class MyDao {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myjdbcTemplate")
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

     public void saveData(obj a) {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("Query", ...);
    }
}
```

I want my `doStuff()` method in the service class to run within a transaction and rollback everything if there is an exception in the `saveData()` method. But this is not running in transaction.

If I add `@Transaction` to a DAO method looks like it runs in separate transaction. Is this correct?

*Update:* I have added a `process()` method to my Service and I call `getFromDao()` and `doStuff()` from `process()`. `process()` is called from the controller. So looks like if I make the service class `@Transactional`, then everything executes within a transaction. But I don't want `getFromDao()` to execute in transaction.

We use just JDBC and no Hibernate.

Comment: It *should* do everything in a unique transaction. How do you know it doesn't? Does  myjdbcTemplate use the same DataSource as simpleDatasourceTxMgr? How are these beans defined?

Comment: @JBNizet Updated above. Also looks like spring do not call transactional advice if the method is called internally..

Comment: No. Transaction management is based on AOP. You need to call the bean from the outside for the transactional interceptor to be able to intercept the call and start a transaction. This is well explained in the documentation. I'm not sure why you wouldn't want getFromDao() to be part of the transaction.

Comment: @JBNizet getFromDao() just does a few select queries to few different tables. So isn't it unnecessary overhead to have that as part of transaction?

Comment: Still it will runs in same transaction if you use default propagation type(which is REQUIRED) and don't change propagation type to REQUIRES_NEW. It will use current transaction if there is.

Comment: I get that it runs as part of existing transaction. But wouldn't it actually unnecessarily lock the rows in table until the transaction is complete?

Comment: @kriver I don't know why everyone thinks having a transaction means overhead. Reading doesn't lock either. You're preoptimizing based on incorrect assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

> You can place the @Transactional annotation before an interface
>   definition, a method on an interface, a class definition, or a public
>   method on a class. However, the mere presence of the @Transactional
>   annotation is not enough to activate the transactional behavior. The
>   @Transactional annotation is simply metadata that can be consumed by
>   some runtime infrastructure that is @Transactional-aware and that can
>   use the metadata to configure the appropriate beans with transactional
>   behavior. In the preceding example, the 
>   element switches on the transactional behavior.

Or if you want annotations you can enable it with

> It is not sufficient to tell you simply to annotate your classes with
>   the @Transactional annotation, add @EnableTransactionManagement to
>   your configuration, and then expect you to understand how it all
>   works. This section explains the inner workings of the Spring
>   Framework’s declarative transaction infrastructure in the event of
>   transaction-related issues.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html